# Не работает программа на javaFX после попытки сортировки по пакетам

Tags: java, javafx

Не запускается программа на javaFX после сортировки по директориям (apps и controllers). В Файле sample.fxml поменял путь.
[image: Код ошибки при попытке скомпилировать код]

Comment: Может покажешь полный стактрейс?  
Похоже ты указываешь не верный путь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй пути "/sample/apps/sample.fxml", "/src/sample/apps/sample.fxml" с и без `/` в начале, один из вариантов должен сработать